# how to copy a list and make changes on the copied list without making changes on the original list

Tags: python, reference, copy

given the following list:

```
l=[1,2,3]
l2=l1[:]
l2[0]=10
print(l)

#[10,2,3]
```

How do I copy the original list and make changes on the copied list without changing the original list (without using `copy.deepcopy(x)`)?

And another question,

if I can create `l2` by assigning `l1` to `l2` why does the `copy()` function exists? does it do anything differently?

`l2=l1`
`l2=l1.copy()`

The things that I tried to do are shown above.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment) might solve the problem!

Comment: You are using list slicing. That should not be a problem in your case. Can you please check your code again?

Comment: Why do you want to make a copy of a list without using a copy function, exactly?

Comment: Your code (if you change `l` to `l1` or otherwise) works exactly as you want. Try it again, please. If it still doesn't work, fix variable naming, please